# My listview is not showing any chats from parse database

Tags: android

I have three classes one user list holds the list of user when each user is clicked it directs you to chat class which holds the chats activity. I also have the conversation list which holds a single conversation. The problem is the list view does not show previous chats stored in parse data base how can I load the previous chats to my list view.

```
package com.example.user.mycareerchat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.user.mycareerchat.custom.CustomActivity;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;



public class UserList extends CustomActivity {
    private static final String EXTRADATA = null;
    // Declare Variables


    //    the chat list
    private ArrayList<ParseUser> uList =new ArrayList<ParseUser>();

    // the parseruser
    public static ParseUser user=new ParseUser();

    /////////////
    public static ArrayList names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String currentUserId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.user_list);







        updateUserStatus(true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        updateUserStatus(false);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadUserList();
    }



    private void loadUserList() {


        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        //don't include yourself
        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", currentUserId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).getUsername().toString());
                        uList = new ArrayList<ParseUser>(userList);


                    }
                    final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
                    ArrayAdapter namesArrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.chat_item, names);
                    list.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,   int i, long l) {
                            //                               openConversation(names, i);
                            String name= names.get(i).toString();
                            startActivity(new Intent(UserList.this,    Chat.class).putExtra(EXTRADATA, name));
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUserStatus(boolean online) {

        user.put("online", online);
        user.saveEventually();

    }

    private class UserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return uList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public ParseUser getItem(int arg0) {
            return uList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {

            if(v!=null)
                v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item,null);

            ParseUser c= getItem(pos);
            TextView lbl = (TextView) v;
            lbl.setText(c.getUsername());
               lbl.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(c.getBoolean("online")?    R.drawable.ic_online:
                            R.drawable.ic_offline,0,
                    R.drawable.arrow,0);
            return v;
        }
    }





}

 //Conversation Class
 package com.example.user.mycareerchat.model;

import com.example.user.mycareerchat.UserList;

import java.util.Date;

 /**
* Created by user on 26/Aug/2015.
*/
public class Conversation {

public static final int STATUS_SENDING =0;

public static final int STATUS_SENT =1;

public static final int STATUS_FAILED =2;

private int status = STATUS_SENT;

private Date date;

private String sender;

private String msg;


//instatiates new conversation
public Conversation(String msg,Date date,String sender) {
    this.msg =msg;
    this.date = date;
    this.sender = sender;
}


//instatiates new conversation
//    public Conversation() {
//
```

//    }

```
public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}

public boolean isSent(){
    return UserList.user.getUsername().equals(sender);
}


public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

```
 //Chat class



  package com.example.user.mycareerchat;

    import android.content.Context;
   import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.provider.Telephony;
    import android.text.InputType;
    import android.text.format.DateUtils;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
     import android.widget.AbsListView;
     import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
     import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.example.user.mycareerchat.custom.CustomActivity;
    import com.example.user.mycareerchat.model.Conversation;
    import com.parse.FindCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class represents single chat class message
 */
public class Chat extends CustomActivity {


    private ArrayList<Conversation> convList;
    private ChatAdapter adp;
    private EditText txt;
    private String buddy;
    private Date lastMsgDate;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private static Handler handler;
    private static final String EXTRA_DATA = null ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.chat);

       convList = new ArrayList<Conversation>();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listchat);
        adp = new ChatAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(adp);
        list.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
        list.setStackFromBottom(true);


        txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);

        setTouchNClick(R.id.btnSend);
        buddy = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_DATA);
       // getActionBar().setTitle(buddy);


        loadConversationList();
        handler = new Handler();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       isRunning =true;
      loadConversationList();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);

        if(v.getId()== R.id.btnSend){
            sendMessage();
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage() {
        if(txt.length()==0)
            return;

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)     getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txt.getWindowToken(),0);


        String s =txt.getText().toString();
        final Conversation c = new Conversation(s, new   Date(),UserList.user.getUsername());
        c.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENDING);
        convList.add(c);
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        txt.setText(null);

        ParseObject po = new ParseObject("Chat");
        po.put("sender",UserList.user.getUsername());
        po.put("receiver",buddy);
        po.put("message",s);
       po.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
       @Override
       public void done(ParseException e) {
        if(e==null)
            c.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_SENT);
        else
            c.setStatus(Conversation.STATUS_FAILED);
        adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});

    }

/*load the conversation list from parse server and save the data of the last message that will
* be used to load only new received messages*/

    private void loadConversationList() {

        //load all messsages

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> q =ParseQuery.getQuery("Chat");
        if(convList.size()==0){
            ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
            al.add(buddy);
            al.add(ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
            q.whereContainedIn("sender", al);
            q.whereContainedIn("receiver",al);
        }
        else{

            //load only new received messages....
             if(lastMsgDate!=null){

                 q.whereLessThan("createdAt",lastMsgDate);
                 q.whereEqualTo("sender",    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                 q.whereEqualTo("receiver",buddy);

                 adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
              //load messages in the most recent order
            q.orderByDescending("createdAt");
            q.setLimit(30);
            q.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> li, ParseException e) {

                    if(li != null && li.size() >0){

                        for (int i =li.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
                            ParseObject po = li.get(i);
                            Conversation c =new      Conversation(po.getString("message"),po.getCreatedAt(),po.getString("sender"));
                            convList.add(c);
                            if(lastMsgDate == null ||    lastMsgDate.before(c.getDate()))

                                lastMsgDate = c.getDate();
                            adp.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        if(isRunning)

                            loadConversationList();

                        }
                    },1000);
//
                }
            });
        }
    }
     /*this class is the adapter class for chat listview. this adapter       shows     the sent and received messages
     *in the list item*/

    private class ChatAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return convList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Conversation getItem(int arg0) {
            return convList.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup arg2) {

            Conversation c = getItem(pos);
            if(c.isSent())
                v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item_sent,null);


            else
                v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.chat_item_rcv,null);
            TextView lbl =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl1);
                            lbl.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(Chat.this,c.getDate().getTime     (),DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS,DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS,0));

            lbl =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl2);
            lbl.setText(c.getMsg());


            lbl =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbl3);
            if (c.isSent()){

                if (c.getStatus()==Conversation.STATUS_SENT)
                    lbl.setText("Delivered");
                else if (c.getStatus()==Conversation.STATUS_SENDING)
                    lbl.setText("Sending...");
                else
                    lbl.setText("Failed");
            }
            else
            lbl.setText("");


            return v;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
   }
```

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries  Use this to retrieve the previous messages stored and then load it into an adapter which will populate your List View

Comment: Post you activity/fragment implementation. These code snippets are not informative.